# AWS Elastic Load Balancing, how to point a subfolder to a blog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I'm using Amazon's ELBs to point to two app servers. I wanted to know, can I use the ELB's to point:

**mysite.com/blog** to a tumblr blog in a reverse proxy type of manner to allow me to host the blog content all under my domain?

Is this possible with amazon's ELBs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry - only EC2 instances can be added to an Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: What would be the best way using EC2/ELB/NGINX/RAILS to have mysite.com/blog point to a blog on tumblr? Thanks

Comment: #1. we are working to avoid the subdomain as that's already in use. 2) What would varnish do?